# Wordpress HTML coding standard for vertical spacing (space between HTML tags)?

Tags: wordpress

I was reading [Wordpress's coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards)

The only confusing part for me is the vertical spacing between HTML code for instance:

**Default Wordpress Theme 3.03:**

**sidebar.php:**

```
<li id="search" class="widget-container widget_search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </li>

            <li id="archives" class="widget-container">
                <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyten' ); ?></h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

(Here's space between the two `<li>` tags)

header.php

```
<div id="masthead">
            <div id="branding" role="banner">
                <?php $heading_tag = ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ? 'h1' : 'div'; ?>
                <<?php echo $heading_tag; ?> id="site-title">
```

(Here, there's no space between `div` tags)

**header.php (line 79...):**

```
</div><!-- #branding -->

            <div id="access" role="navigation">
              <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu.  The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used.  If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used.  */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- #access -->
        </div><!-- #masthead -->
    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="main">
```

(Here, there's is space between those 3 `<div>` tags

What's the coding standard of vertical spacing (I don't think it is random)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i really follow you, but some examples..

## Well formatted HTML

Indentation used, no excessive whitespace

```
<div class="example1">
    <div class="example2">
        <div class="example3"></div>
        <div class="example4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Poorly formatted HTML - Example 1

No indentation

```
<div class="example1">
<div class="example2">
<div class="example3"></div>
<div class="example4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

## Example 2

Useless whitespace

```
    <div class="example1">



                <div class="example2">
                    <div class="example3"></div>
                                <div class="example4"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This isn't really specific to WordPress, any good teacher or tutorial will encourage well formatted coding, and there's little excuse when you're using a good editor(i mean seriously, which do you find most readable and easier to understand?).

More..

## Well formatted PHP

Indentation used appropriately

```
if( something ) {
    do_something()
    if( some_nested_condition )
        do_something_else();
}
```

## Poorly formatted

No indentation, harder to read

```
if( something ) {
do_something()
if( some_nested_condition )
do_something_else();
}
```

Formatting your code makes it easier to read, understand, or update/maintain(it's not something that will make a whole lot of sense until you start dealing with code on a regular basis). Then again, i'm not the best at explaining these things, so i'd suggest refering to information already available for the "why".. (i know my reasons)..

## Mixed PHP and HTML example

Mock template loop, only for illustration

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>My Website Heading</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

    <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="wrapsallposts">

            <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="postcontent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good examples. In this case, I was wondering about how to properly nest HTML tags (the vertical space between elements).

Comment: It really depends on the code you're dealing with, but generally a single line of whitespace(i feel) is acceptable for seperating a PHP code block from a HTML code block(such as when you performing an iteration of some data where you're outputing HTML for each iteration).

Comment: That said it depends what the code looks like, i'll add another example above with a mix of PHP and HTML, and show you how i'd personally format it..